# How to remove whitespace following numbers in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, vba

I copy and paste the following data from Yahoo Finance. However, the numbers(with commas) in the table are recognized as texts. Also, in each cell with numbers, two whitespace are followed. I am trying to remove the whitespace and convert all "numbers" to numbers so that I can do some data analysis.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LkX6MnC9XPcjYwTmVFQUV0NG8/view?usp=sharing

I tried the trim function in EXCEL, but I failed. Is there some quick way to remove the white space following the numbers?

Comment: I just tried pasting a number + comas + spaces ... if the format is set to general, it'll figure out it's a number just fine. The only way it treats it as text, is if the format for the cells is set to text. Change that first, then try repasting ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting them with either of the two formulas below:

```
In E5, type this:
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE(B5, ",", "")), CHAR(160), ""))
```

It appears that the last 2 characters have a code of 160 as determined by `=CODE(RIGHT(B5,1))` and `=CODE(RIGHT(B5,2))`. So we just simply replace them with blanks.

or

```
In E5, type this:
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B5, 1, LEN(B5)-2), ",", ""))
```

In the above case, we strip off the last 2 characters and then do substitution on it.

Comment: After you receive answers, please always make sure to close out your question by check marking one that worked best for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, you may use this small VBA code whenever you want:

Sub test()

```
For i = 3 To 49
    For j = 2 To 5
        If Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(i, j).Value = Trim(Cells(i, j).Value)
            Cells(i, j).Value = Left(Cells(i, j).Value, Len(Cells(i, j).Value) - 2)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

End Sub

It will iterate through all the cells from `B3` to `D49` and will remove two blank spaces. This will convert the format to number automatically.